# Create instance of class from object returned by api call

Tags: angular, typescript, mongoose

I am retrieving an Object from a mongoose api, and I need to turn it into an instance of a custom class. Currently I have it set up to manually pass the Object's members into the constructor of the Ingredient class to create a new Ingredient like so:

ingredient.model.ts:

```
export class Ingredient {
    quantity: number;
    unit: string;
    description: string;
    ...

    constructor(quantity: number, unit: string, description: string, ...) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.description = description;
        ...
    }
}
```

someComponent.component.ts:

```
import { Ingredient } from "ingredient.model.ts"

foo: Ingredient;

ngOnInit() {
    api.getIngredient(id).subscribe((ingredient) => {
        this.foo = ingredient;
    });

    let newIngredient = new Ingredient(foo.quantity, foo.unit, foo.description, ...)
}
```

I'm sure there's a much cleaner way to do this that allows me to avoid tediously assigning each member. I'm wanting to something along the lines of this with a constructor that just "magically" converts the object to an instance of Ingredient:

```
api.getIngredient(id).subscribe((ingredient) => {
    let newIngredient = new Ingredient(ingredient);
});
```

Comment: Why not use the interface? https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response

Answer (score 0):

Your Model

```
export class Ingredient {
    quantity: number;
    unit: string;
    description: string;

    constructor(data?) {
        data = data || {};
        this.quantity = data.quantity;
        this.unit = data.unit;
        this.description = data.description;
    }
}
```

Your Component

```
import { Ingredient } from "ingredient.model.ts"

foo: Ingredient;

ngOnInit() {
    this.foo = new Ingredient({});
    api.getIngredient(id).subscribe((ingredient) => {
        this.foo = new Ingredient(ingredient);
    });

    let newIngredient = new Ingredient(this.foo)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an interface and `getIngredient` returns an `Observable<Ingredient>`?

Example:

#### Ingredient Interface

```
export interface Ingredient {
    quantity: number;
    unit: string;
    description: string;
    ...
}
```

#### API Service

```
public getIngredient(id: string | yourType): Observable<Ingredient> {
  .... 
  return httpService.get<Ingredient>(...);
}
```

#### Component

```
api.getIngredient(id).subscribe((ingredient) = this.foo = ingredient);
```

In this way, you are telling that the response of `getIngredient` is an `Ingredient` interface and you don't need the assign the property.

Of course this is valid **only** if you don't have any methods inside `Ingredient`, otherwise you have to switch to `class` but the logic is the same